# Can't use PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've installed PyInstaller through pip on Python 3.5.2 but I can't get it to work.

After running the command prompt in the folder where the .py file is and typing in 'PyInstaller practicaGUI.py' I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfVdA.jpg) error.

Is there a way to solve this?
If not, what are the alternatives?

EDIT:

My pyinstaller-script.py looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Az7.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening `pyinstall-script.py` from your error message in a text editor (like Notepad++) and convert it to UTF-8 explicitly. The message says the encoding is wrong.

While on it, look out for broken characters in the code that aren't displayed correctly. Retype them, save, try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked the file but I haven't been able to find any non UTF-8 character. I've edited the OP with a photo of the pyinstaller-script.py in case you want to check it out.

Comment: I just realised, the `\xe1` character from the error message is the latin-1 representaion of "á" in your script's path name, which appears in your script, too. Try removing that comment in the first line.