# Pyinstaller gives error regarding no encoding declared

Tags: python, encoding, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile a Python script using Pyinstaller and I get the following message when running it:

```
File "C:\Users\AlexQuiñonez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf1' in file C:\Users\AlexQuiñonez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

[image]

I am lost regarding this and could use any help I get.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-` as suggested [in the link given](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a separate thread, given by Jeronimo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46619360/10472412)

"Try opening pyinstall-script.py from your error message in a text editor (like Notepad++) and convert it to UTF-8 explicitly."